# Location status bar icon displayed when listening for StatusChanged on Geolocator

Tags: windows, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm building an app for Windows 10 Mobile, and I'd like it to know when the location authorization status changes so it can enable/disable location features. I've run into this issue where users always see the icon indicating that an app is accessing their location in the phone's status bar. It seems that simply adding a listener for StatusChanged (and not for PositionChanged) is enough to cause this icon to appear, which doesn't make sense because the app isn't requesting any location information yet.

I would like to be able to detect authorization status changes even without having gotten the user's location, but this is making users think the app is tracking their location (violating their privacy and draining their battery) even when it isn't.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this icon from appearing when I'm not actually listening for location updates?

Here's some (ugly) code that demonstrates this:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Geolocator::RequestAccessAsync();

    static Geolocator ^g;
    g = ref new Geolocator();
    g->StatusChanged += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::Devices::Geolocation::Geolocator ^, Windows::Devices::Geolocation::StatusChangedEventArgs ^>(this, &LocationIndicatorTest::MainPage::OnStatusChanged);
}


void LocationIndicatorTest::MainPage::OnStatusChanged(Windows::Devices::Geolocation::Geolocator ^sender, Windows::Devices::Geolocation::StatusChangedEventArgs ^args)
{
    OutputDebugStringW(L"Status changed\n");
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call 'Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync()' to get your permission status?

Comment: I could use that to poll, but not to know immediately when the user has disabled or enabled location access.

Comment: But your app gets put to background (suspended event), when the user switches to settings, so you only need to check on activation.